# Array.reduce somewhat complex statement?

Tags: javascript

```
export default function compose(...funcs) {
  if (funcs.length === 0) {
    return arg => arg
  }

  if (funcs.length === 1) {
    return funcs[0]
  }

  // what does this line do???
  return funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
}
```

I'm reading [compose.js](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.js) source code from redux module. I know basics of reduce function, it just calls the reducer in every element in the collection and returns a single output. It has an accumulator to store the intermediary results and to pass it in each call of the reducer. But reduce in this code is somewhat vague for me, can someone explain it in layman terms?

Answer (score 0):

`(a, b)` can be written as `(previousComposition, currectFunc)`. The result of the reducing is a function taking `(...args)` - none or more arguments.

Every "loop" of reducing returns a function which composes previous composition with the current function `a(b(...args))` - it can be understood as `(a . b)(x) = a(b(x))`.

Only a function is returned, it means the functions are not executed yet. It happens first, when the result composition function is called: `var res = compose(a, b)(x)`

Example:

```
var plus1 = x => x + 1;
var plus2 = x => x + 2;
var mult2 = x => x * 2;

var composedFn = compose(mult2, plus2, plus1); 
// (...x) => mult2(plus2(plus1(...x))) 

var res = composedFn(3);

console.log(res); // 12
```

As you can see in the example, first `plus1` was applied, then `plus2` and finally `mult2`.